# How can I change the Mapbox-gl maki icons color?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am working **Mapbox-gl.js** (v0.38.0) with **Maki** icons, **Ionic3 & angular4**. I don't want to use mapbox.js. I have done what I want but by default the icon color is "**brown**" in color. But I want it as "**green**" in color.

I tried similar as [mapbox-gl example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/) the following link,

How can I customize the color and other icon properties

Comment: is the icon sdf or non-sdf? - non-sdf fonts are not supported
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2730#issuecomment-254879029